# HOW CAN I CONVERT THIS 11%2F13%2F2017%2000%3A00%3A00 STRING INTO DATE FROMATE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I have a column which is having this type of string data `11%2F13%2F2017%2000%3A00%3A00` and I want to convert it into date format.

Is there any fast way to do that because cast and convert doesn't works.

That data comes from a live database table. I have a fulltext column like this:

```
&Invoice_Date_Start=11%2F13%2F2017%2000%3A00%3A00&I‌​
nvoice_Date_End=11%2‌​F19%2F2017%2000%3A00‌​%3A00&
```

From where I am extracting using various combination of substring and left function a column name invoice start date and getting that data which i have posted earlier. Now I need to convert it to date format.

Comment: Ok, first why you are storing date as string and like this format? second what would be the result for the string you provided? what is the logic? Can you please edit the question give sample data and desired uotputs with explanation.

Comment: Also define _cast and convert doesn't works_ and show what did you try

Comment: As I can understand there is two dates there _Invoice_Date_Start_ and _I‌​nvoice_Date_End_. Which one you need? or both of them?

Comment: i need both but once i got the one the other is the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's URL encoded. Use the UrlDecode function from this link and then cast it:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005508/URL-Decode-in-T-SQL

```
select cast(dbo.UrlDecode('11%2F13%2F2017%2000%3A00%3A00') as datetime)
```

[Edit]
If you're restricted from creating the function, and you only need to replace the same few characters every time for a single, consistent field, you can just use REPLACE:

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('11%2F13%2F2017%2000%3A00%3A00', '%2F', '/'), '%20', ' '), '%3A', ':') AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: HI i am on Live database and i can't create that function there. so any other way to do that without creating function. thanks